# Changing css of SVG with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, svg, jquery-svg

I am trying to get the eye color of this image to change when a button is clicked. The entire svg is included in the jsfiddle link but here is the element I am trying to target:

```
 <ellipse class="eye-color" fill="#1b6811" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-linecap="null" cx="274" cy="285" rx="31" ry="35"/>
```

css:

```
.eye-color{
  fill: blue;
}
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $(".eye_color").css('fill', 'red');
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q85je4tv/1/

This code is not working, thanks for any help.

Edit: Just noticed the tag 'jquery-svg', is this plugin required to manipulate svg images with jQuery?

Comment: typo error `eye_color` --> `eye-color`

Comment: wow... thanks I probably would have never caught that